# Bootstrap buttons not getting highlighted when clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have an app with 3 buttons, the 3 buttons make an AJAX call to retrieve some data and redraw a table with the data. However when clicked the button should be kept highlighted so the user knows which data they are viewing.

This is the JS code that calls the Web API method:

```
   iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaActividades = function (filtro) {
        var idObjetivoValue = sessionStorage.idObjetivoValue;
        $('#tab_vista1').html('<br><br><br><img class="loadImage" src="Images/loader.gif" />');
        $.ajax({
            url: 'IniciativasEstrategicasWebPart/GetVistaActividades',
            type: 'POST',
            data: {
                idObjetivo: idObjetivoValue,
                filtro: filtro
            },
            success: function (data) {
                drawVistaActividades(data);
            },
            error: function (data) {
                showErrorMessage(data);
            }
        });
    }
```

This is the method that draws the data:

```
 function drawVistaActividades(data) {
        resetBreadCrumb();
        var html = "";
        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
            html += template.rowVistaActividades
                .replace("{0}", data[i].nombreActividad)
                .replace("{1}", data[i].iniciativaName)
                .replace("{2}", data[i].fechaVencimiento)
                .replace("{3}", data[i].fechaRealTerminacion)
                .replace("{4}", data[i].responsables);
        }
        $("#tab_vistaActividades").html("<br>" + "<br>" + template.tableVistaActividades.replace("{0}", html));
    }
```

This is the table template that I use to draw the data, and the buttons are there

```
tableVistaActividades: "<div>" +
                                    "<div>" + 
                                        "<div class=\"btn-group\" role=\"group\" aria-label=\"Basic example\">" +
                                          "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onclick=\"iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaActividades('A tiempo')\">A tiempo</button>" +
                                          "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onclick=\"iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaActividades('Atrasadas')\">Atrasadas</button>" +
                                          "<button type=\"button\" class=\"btn btn-default\" onclick=\"iniciativasEstrategicas.GetVistaActividades('Pendientes')\">Pendientes</button>" +
                                        "</div>" +
                                    "</div>" + 
                                    "<table class='table'>" +
                                        "<thead>" +
                                            "<tr>" +
                                                "<th>" +
                                                    "Actividad" +
                                                "</th>" +
                                                "<th>" +
                                                    "Iniciativa" +
                                                "</th>" +
                                                "<th>" +
                                                    "Fecha propuesta" +
                                                "</th>" +
                                                "<th>" +
                                                    "Fecha real terminación" +
                                                "</th>" +
                                                "<th>" +
                                                    "Responsables" +
                                                "</th>" +
                                            "</tr>" +
                                        "</thead>" +
                                        "<tbody>" +
                                            "{0}" +
                                        "</tbody>" +
                                    "</table>" +"<div>",
```

and the row template

```
rowVistaActividades: "<tr>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "{0}" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "{1}" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "{2}" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "{3}" +
                        "</td>" +
                        "<td>" +
                            "{4}" +
                        "</td>" +
                    "</tr>",
```

As you can see in [this page](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups).

We are using the same Bootstrap button code and in that page the button remains highlighted when clicked.

Comment: Actually the button doesn't remain 'highlighted', it just stays focused. Check out the buttons-plugin for radio-style buttons: http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should solve your problem, basically you need to add "active" to selected option and remove "active" from siblings which was previously selected.

```
$(".btn-group > .btn").click(function(){
    $(this).addClass("active").siblings().removeClass("active");
    $(this).addClass("active");
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As @taTrifynor said in the comment, you should simply use [Button groups](http://getbootstrap.com/components/#btn-groups) with `input type="radio"`, read [about it](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#buttons-checkbox-radio). For example:

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sergdenisov/p12oxcyz/1/)

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="btn-group" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option1" autocomplete="off" checked="checked"/>Button 1 (preselected)
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option2" autocomplete="off"/>Button 2
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" name="options" id="option3" autocomplete="off"/>Button 3
    </label>
</div>
```

Or I don't understand what do you want.